# display non-printable ascii characters in SQL as :ascii: or :print: does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, toad

I am trying to fetch all non-printable ASCII characters from DESCRIPTION field in a table using SQL in TOAD however the below query is not working .

```
select 
regexp_instr(a.description,'[^[:ascii:]]') as description from
poline a where a.ponum='XXX' and a.siteid='YYY' and 
regexp_instr(a.description,'[^[:ascii:]]') > 0
```

the above query bought error ORA-127729: invalid character class in regular expression. I tried :print: instead of :ascii: however it didn't bring any result. Below is the description for this record which has non-printable characters.

```
Sherlock 16 x 6.5” Wide Wheelbarrow wheel .M100P.10R – Effluent care bacteria and enzyme formulation
```

Comment: Thanks max092012.  Are you looking to get every occurrence of a non-printable character per row, or only the first occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:ascii:` is not a valid character class, and even if it were, it doesn't appear to be what you are trying to get here (ascii does contain non-printable characters).  Valid classes can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm).

Actually if you replace `:ascii:` with `:print:` in your original query, it will indeed return the first position in each `POLINE.DESCRIPTION` that is a non-printable character.  (If it returns nothing for you, it may be because your `DESCRIPTION` data is actually all printable.)

But as you stated you want to identify ***Every*** non-printable char in each `DESCRIPTION` in `POLINE`, some changes would be needed.  I'll include an example that gets every match as a starting place.

In this example, each `DESCRIPTION` will be decomposed to its individual constituent characters, and each char will be checked for printability.  The location within the `DESCRIPTION` string along with the `ASCII number` of the non-printable character will be returned.

This example assumes there is a unique identifier for each row in `POLINE`, here called `POLINE_ID`.

First, create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE POLINE(
  POLINE_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  PONUM VARCHAR2(32),
  SITEID VARCHAR2(32),
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(256)
);
```

And load some data.  I inserted a couple non-printing chars in the example `Sherlock` string you provided, `#23` and `#17`.  An example string composed of only the first 64 ASCII chars (of which the first 31 are not in `:print:`) is also included, and some fillers to fall through the `PONUM` and `SITEID` predicates.

```
INSERT INTO POLINE VALUES (1,'XXX','YYY','Sherlock'||CHR(23)||' 16 x 6.5” Wide Wheelbarrow wheel .M100P.10R –'||CHR(17)||' Effluent care bacteria and enzyme formulation');

DECLARE
  V_STRING VARCHAR2(64) := CHR(1);
BEGIN
  FOR POINTER IN 2..64 LOOP
    V_STRING := V_STRING||CHR(POINTER);
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO POLINE VALUES (2, 'XXX','YYY',V_STRING);
  INSERT INTO POLINE VALUES (3, 'AAA','BBB',V_STRING);
END;
/

INSERT INTO POLINE VALUES(4,'XXX','YYY','VOLTRON');
```

Now we have 4 rows total.  Three of them contain (multiple) non-printable characters, but only two of them should match all the restrictions.

Then run a query.  There are two example queries below--the first uses `REGEXP_INSTR` with as in your initial example query (substituting `:cntrl:` for `:print:`).  But for an alternative, a 2nd, variant is also included that just checks whether each char is in the first 31 ascii chars.

Both example queries, will index every char of each `DESCRIPTION`, and check whether it is printable, and collect the ascii number and location of each non-printable character in each candidate `DESCRIPTION`.  The example table here has `DESCRIPTION`s that are 256 chars long, so this is used as the max index in the cartesian join.

Please note, these are ***not efficient***, and are designed to get **EVERY** match.  If you end up only needing the first match afterall, your original query replaced with `:print:` will perform much better.  Also, this could also be tuned by dropping into PL/SOL or perhaps going recursive (if PL/SQL is allowed in your use case, or you are 11gR2+, etc.).  Also some predicates here such as `REGEXP_LIKE` do not impact the end result and serve only to allow preliminary filtration.  These could be superfluous (or worse) for you, depending on your data set.

First example, using regex and `:print:`

```
SELECT
  POLINE_ID,
  STRING_INDEX                                                                     AS NON_PRINTABLE_LOCATION,
  ASCII(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION, STRING_INDEX, 1), '[[:cntrl:]]', 1, 1)) AS NON_PRINTABLE_ASCII_NUMBER
FROM POLINE
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS STRING_INDEX
              FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY LEVEL < 257) CANDIDATE_LOCATION
WHERE PONUM = 'XXX'
      AND SITEID = 'YYY'
      AND REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, '[[:cntrl:]]')
      AND REGEXP_INSTR(SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION, STRING_INDEX, 1), '[[:cntrl:]]', 1, 1, 0) > 0
      AND STRING_INDEX <= LENGTH(DESCRIPTION)
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

Second example, using ASCII numbers:

```
SELECT
  POLINE_ID,
  STRING_INDEX                                AS NON_PRINTABLE_LOCATION,
  ASCII(SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION, STRING_INDEX, 1)) AS NON_PRINTABLE_ASCII_NUMBER
FROM POLINE
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS STRING_INDEX
              FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY LEVEL < 257) CANDIDATE_LOCATION
WHERE PONUM = 'XXX'
      AND SITEID = 'YYY'
      AND REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, '[[:cntrl:]]')
      AND ASCII(SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION, STRING_INDEX, 1)) BETWEEN 1 AND 31
      AND STRING_INDEX <= LENGTH(DESCRIPTION)
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

In our test data, these queries will produce equivalent output. We should expect this to have two hits (for chrs 17 and 23) in the `Sherlock` `DESCRIPTION`, and 31 hits for the first-64-ascii `DESCRIPTION`.

Result:

```
POLINE_ID  NON_PRINTABLE_LOCATION  NON_PRINTABLE_ASCII_NUMBER  
1          9                       23                          
1          56                      17                          
2          1                       1                           
2          2                       2                           
2          3                       3                           
2          4                       4                           
2          5                       5                           
2          6                       6                           
2          7                       7                           
2          8                       8                           
2          9                       9                           
2          10                      10                          
2          11                      11                          
2          12                      12                          
2          13                      13                          
2          14                      14                          
2          15                      15                          
2          16                      16                          
2          17                      17                          
2          18                      18                          
2          19                      19                          
2          20                      20                          
2          21                      21                          
2          22                      22                          
2          23                      23                          
2          24                      24                          
2          25                      25                          
2          26                      26                          
2          27                      27                          
2          28                      28                          
2          29                      29                          
2          30                      30                          
2          31                      31                       

33 rows selected.
```

**EDIT** In response to comments, here is some elaboration on what we can expect from `[[:cntrl:]]` and `[^[:cntrl:]]` with `regexp_instr`.

`[[:cntrl:]]` will match any of the first 31 ascii characters, while `[^[:cntrl:]]` is the logical negation of `[[:cntrl:]]`, so it will match anything except the first 31 ascii characters.
To compare these, we can start with the simplest case of only one character, `ascii #31`.  Since there's only one character, the result can only be either match or miss.  One will expect the following to return `1` for the match:

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(CHR(31),'[[:cntrl:]]',1,1,0) AS MATCH_INDEX FROM DUAL;

MATCH_INDEX
1
```

But 0 for the miss with negating [^[:cntrl:]] :

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(CHR(31),'[^[:cntrl:]]',1,1,0) AS MATCH_INDEX FROM DUAL;

MATCH_INDEX
0
```

Now if we include two (or more) characters that are a mix of printable and non-printnable, there are more possible outcomes.  ***Both*** `[[:cntrl:]]` and `[^[:cntrl:]]` can match, but they can only match different things.  If we move from only ascii `#31` to ascii `#64#31`, we will still expect `[[:cntrl:]]` to match (since there is a non-printable character in the second position) but it should now return 2, since the non-printable is in the second position.

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(CHR(64)||CHR(31),'[[:cntrl:]]',1,1,0) AS MATCH_INDEX FROM DUAL;

MATCH_INDEX
2
```

And now `[^[:cntrl:]]` *also* has the opportunity to match (at the first position):

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(CHR(64)||CHR(31),'[^[:cntrl:]]',1,1,0) AS MATCH_INDEX FROM DUAL;

MATCH_INDEX
1
```

When there are a mix of printable and control characters, both `[[:cntrl:]]` and `[^[:cntrl:]]` can match, but they will match at different indices.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. My requirement is to pick non- printable ascii characters in any position in description field. I ran into some test and [^[:cntrl:]] works however [[:cntrl:]]+ also work but they both bring in different results. Can you please elaborate the difference between the same ? thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks @max092012 It'll be a few hours (late in my timezone) but sure I'll follow up about [^[:cntrl:]] vs [[:cntrl:]].  The effective matcher generated by these is indeed different, so it seems reasonable they'd produce different results. In your case, I believe [:cntrl:] are your targets. I'll follow up after I add some about these character classes. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @max092012 I added a section at the bottom of the post about the behavior of `regexp_instr` with `[[:cntrl:]]` vs `[^[:cntrl:]]` against different combinations of characters.  Does this help to clarify the queries?  Thanks

Comment: thanks once again for the elaborate explanation. [^[:cntrl:]] would bring in any non- printable characters ( beyond 127) ? What if I want to pick both ASCII before 31 and after 127 using the same query ? I do understand that I can use [^[:cntrl:]]  but would this satisfy all ascii which is not between 31-127 ?

Comment: Thanks @max092012 [[:cntrl:]] will match chr 127, but not chrs 128, 129, etc.  [^[:cntrl:]] will not match chr 127 but will match chrs 128, 129, etc.  Using character classes (like [:cntrl:]), you can match multiple ranges of ascii chars, it just depends on your goals.  [:cntrl:] matches 1-31, but also 127, so it can match both in a single query.  In your case, you'd mentioned trying to find all non-printable, so using [^[:print]] or [[:cntrl:]] are good candidates.  If you repeat my example 64-character query with 128 or 256 chars, you can see all the matches over the range.  Thanks